# Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘midasml’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):

Tags: r, installation, midasr

I am trying to download the midasml package. My R version is 4.2.0. When I install the package I get no errors. But when I try library(midasml) I get this error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘midasml’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):  there is no package called ‘mcGlobaloptim’
```

I found on the Internet that mcGlobaloptim is removed from the CRAN package. I tried to install it but it does not work and I get:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘mcGlobaloptim’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I'll assume your OS is linux. Download `mcGlobalOptim`, from archive, then in terminal `R CMD INSTALL ~/Downloads/mcGlobaloptim_0.1.tar.gz` ...`* DONE (mcGlobaloptim)`, then install `midasml`. Hope that works.